# Ubuntuy 18.04 on a new DELL Inspiron French Canadian keyboard does not work correctly. How cure?

Tags: keyboard, dell, keyboard-layout

Have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new DELL Inspiron 15 3000 with a French Canadian keyboard and have tried all four Ubuntu keyboard files. Using Multilingual setting, most, but not all keys work and NO function keys work using any of the four choices. They only act using the small icons below each function key.

Ubuntu does do work directly with the DELL company, right?

Then, how do I get a keyboard file to work with the DELL French Canadian keyboard?

Please forward this to someone who works directly with DELL.

Comment: I'm not working with DELL, but still... Have you tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and changed to a suitable keyboard model? There are a few Dell options there.

Comment: Sorry to be so late answering. When I did use your sudo command, I got the following DELL options: DELL, DELL 101-key PC, DELL Inspiron 6000/8000 laptop, DELL Lattitude laptop,DELL Precision M65 laptop, DELL Precision M laptop, DELL SK-8125, DELL SK-8135, DELL USB Multimedia, DELL Wireless Desktop.
The above sudo ended with the following both for DELL Inspiron 6000/8000 laptop and for DELL:  W: Possible missing firmwware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3fw for module r8169, and W: Possible missing firmwware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3fw for module r8169 - So...?

Comment: I think you can disregard those warning messages. The question is: If you pick a suitable DELL option and reboot, do you notice a difference?

Comment: No. And Function keys still do not work and some option keys also do not work. I have three external French Canadian keyboards but non like the DELL one. My three external ones all work well with simply the Ubuntu French Canadian choice. But NOT our new DELL.

Comment: I see. Then, as you said, you probably need help from someone with Dell experience.

Comment: I do have a programmer friend who is working on developing one but I will share your suggestion with him. Fortunately, one from Ubuntu has most keys working but not all.